# URLConnection cannot read any header fields but firefox does

Tags: java, https, urlconnection

I'm trying to get header fields from this url using URLConnection in java

```
https://farm9.staticflickr.com/8709/16206420933_5d7427b8e3_o_d.jpg 

URL fUrl = new URL(url);
                URLConnection connection = fUrl.openConnection();
                for (Map.Entry<String, List<String>> k : connection.getHeaderFields().entrySet()) {
                    System.out.println(k.toString());
                }//Return nothing
```

But i can't get any fields from this link while firefox have the conent-length, accept-ranges ...

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK

Date: Wed, 18 Mar 2015 02:44:58 GMT

Content-Type: image/jpeg

Content-Length: 11734133

p3p: policyref="http://info.yahoo.com/w3c/p3p.xml", CP="CAO DSP COR CUR ADM DEV TAI PSA PSD IVAi IVDi CONi TELo OTPi OUR DELi SAMi OTRi UNRi PUBi IND PHY ONL UNI PUR FIN COM NAV INT DEM CNT STA POL HEA PRE LOC GOV"

x-photo-origin: gq1

Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=16206420933_5d7427b8e3_o.jpg

Pragma: no-cache

Expires: 0

Last-Modified: Sun, 15 Mar 2015 20:53:26 GMT

Accept-Ranges: bytes

Age: 0

Via: http/1.1 photocache907.flickr.gq1.yahoo.com (ApacheTrafficServer [cMsSf ]), http/1.1 cache127.flickr.sg3.yahoo.com (ApacheTrafficServer [cMsSf ])

Server: ATS

ytracetag: 000100080000000100000000000000003e5ac2bfd747bd07000000000000000013cc77a17690ed0013cc77a183c7b900592ecf220000000022cf2e594d34a5ef

X-Firefox-Spdy: 3.1
```

[image]

So what can i do in this case, thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There aren't any header fields until you call `connect(),` `getInputStream()`, or `getResponseCode().`

Comment: Thanks, i found a tutorial about your comment [doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/urls/connecting.html)